# gnome-terminal fallback font

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts

I display weird glyphs in my gnome-terminal. My font is Terminus, which does not implement many of the UTF-8 glyphes.

Yet, the glyphes look ok.

So does emacs, and when I check the font used instead of Terminus, it tells me it's Symbola.

The questions are:

- how do I look up what gnome-terminal uses as a fallback?
- how do I change what it uses as a fallback?
- bonus: is there any ready to apt-get font that has the "right-pointing black triangle" take the whole heigth of a character? (yes, pimping my prompt)

Comment: For your first two questions: I don't think gnome-terminal does anything special here. Fallback is handled by fontconfig. I think you should study fontconfig to see how a fallback can be defined.

Comment: For your last question: I'm not aware of such font, and I don't think that character is supposed to take the whole height. Even the "powerline" zsh prompt/theme/font uses a private Unicode codepoint for that glyph rather than piggybacking U+25B6.

Comment: @egmont: here's a screenshot of my term, some chars do seem to reach all the way up and all the way down? Otherwise there would be no box drawing... http://i.imgur.com/9bQJByz.png

Comment: gnome-terminal has a special code to draw these characters manually rather than taking them from the font. But sure taking them from the font could also result in them occupying the entire cell. Technically it is possible to create a font where U+25B6 takes up the entire height and width of cell, as you wish; just as it is possible to create a font where the letter "A" looks like "B". I believe noone has done this because U+25B6 is not supposed to look like that.

Comment: I recommend that you install the `fonts-powerline` package which contains such glyphs at the U+E0B0..U+E0B3 codepoints. It seems to perform some fontconfig magic so that it automatically hooks up to the other fonts (at least to the one I'm using [Monospace Regular], I did not have to change anything and these glyphs have just appeared).

Comment: @egmont: cool, thanks! It doesn't work with Terminus, but it does work with Monospace. Any idea why? Maybe because Terminus does not implement \ue0b0, while Monospace does?

Comment: No clue about this, sorry.